# Parsing a ulong into two uint variables in c#

Tags: c#, performance, parsing

I have a series of `ulong` instances, each of which contains two separate values. The first 4 bytes represents one `uint` value and the second 4 bytes represent another. What is the most efficient means of parsing the `ulong` into two `uint` variables? This will be occurring in tight loops so I’m looking for the fastest possible pattern.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Two options:

- use `unsafe` code or *abuse* an explicit-layout `struct` (as a union) to rip it into pieces silently
- use shift operations

I'd usually prefer the latter; i.e.

```
uint x = (uint)(value & 0xFFFFFFFF), y = (uint)((value >> 32)&0xFFFFFFFF)
```

In addition to working in more environments (not all VMs allow `unsafe`), this avoids any risk of confusion on a different-endian machine (using Mono, perhaps).

The `unsafe` version would be something like:

```
uint* ptr = (uint*)(void*)&value;
uint x = ptr[0], y = ptr[1];
```

For which is faster: try is both options and time t! A micro-optimisation can only be evaluated in a specific code-context.

Comment: Thanks... I tested three variations. (**1**) Managed shift [*above*], (**2**) Unsafe shift [*also above*], and (**3**) BitConverter variation. My tests showed that the Managed shift variation is fastest (*then 2 then 3*). Thanks, I'm going with option **1**.

Comment: @MarcGravell Out of curiosity, could you show me the reverse... e.g. take two `uint` variables and merge them into a `ulong`?

Comment: @Joe `value = ((ulong)x) | (((ulong)y) << 32);`

Comment: @Joe just terminology: #2 is not a "shift" ( `<<` and `>>` are the "shift" operators). It is just unsafe access to the raw memory.

Answer (score 3):

You could also so an explicitly layout a struct with overlapping fields (which is like a C union).

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
struct SplitStruct
{
 [FieldOffset(0)]
 public ulong ulongValue;

 [FieldOffset(0)]
 public uint uintValue1;

 [FieldOffset(4)]
 public unit uintValue2;
}
```

Although personally I'd still use the bit shift.  The explicitly laid out struct hides what's happening and is pretty obscure.

Comment: I alluded to this one, but it is definitely worth having this as a full example - good addition